# arithmetic coding for generating random number with desired distribution

Tags: arithmetic, coding-theory, pseudo-random-generators, random-number-generator

Hi i want to convert random number with uniform distribution to desired distribution using arithmetic coding. It has been done in the following research paper called arithmetic distribution coding available in the following research paper.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3931.pdf
 Kindly can any one guide me how come arithmetic coding has been exploited in achieving a desired distribution. The main purpose of this is to optimized the distribution of data for transmission in gaussian noise channel.

Comment: Have you read the paper?

Comment: Yeap but still i haven't grasped the basic idea of it..

Comment: Reading research papers is a skill that has to be acquired. The only way to get better at it is to spend time doing it. Accept that it could take some time to understand a research paper, especially in the beginning.